# How can I fetch a binary data stream via scala?

Tags: facebook, scala, databinder

I want to download an image for a given url in a scala program. I am trying to do something like the following but all the dispatcher examples I can find talk about text, not data streams. Can anyone point me to examples of downloading binary from a url using dispatch? If I try an use img directly the compiler barfs about Future.

The task I am trying to carry out is retrieving the facebook profile image.

```
  def copyUrl( uri : String ) : Array[Byte] = {
    val svc = url(uri)
    val img = Http(svc OK as.Bytes)
    for ( i <- img )  {
      println(i)
    }
    // something here but no idea
    img.map(_.toArray)
  }
```

I get the following compiler error

```
ProfileImage.scala:31: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Array[Byte]]
[error]  required: Array[Byte]
[error]           img.map(_.toArray)
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
```

I have also tried

```
  def copyUrl( uri : String ) : Array[Byte] = {
    result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(uri).map(_.toByte).toArray
  }
```

which results in

```
Exception being returned to browser when processing /oauth/welcome java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dispatch is returning a `Future` for the `Array[Byte]` to you, so you need to apply the Future in order to get the `Array[Byte]`.  Try changing the following line:

```
val img = Http(svc OK as.Bytes)()
```

Notice that I added a `()` to the end of that line.  This will apply the `Future`, blocking and waiting for the result.  Blocking is not ideal, and the dispach `Future` also supports async callbacks, but this works for the purpose of your example to show what was missing.